# Vertical QLabel, or the equivalent?

Tags: c++, qt

I want axis labels for a plot I'm making, and naturally the y-axis label should be oriented vertically.  I'm pretty sure `QwtPlot` does this, but I'm trying to keep things light so I'm just using a simple `QWidget` + `QPainter` for now.  I didn't see any way to change `QLabel` orientation in the documentation.  Some solutions are given in [this 2002 thread](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2002-09/msg00357.html) but I'd like something that doesn't seem like such a hack.  I'm using Qt 4.8 now, is there really no way to do this aside from `QPainter::drawText()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So indeed I gave up on finding any simple way to achieve this, and looking over Uwe Rathmann's Qwt code indeed he uses `QPainter::drawText()` in his `QwtPainter::drawText` wrapper function, and a `QTransform` to achieve the rotation, in `QwtScaleDraw::labelTransformation`.  So I've just put these together as follows:

```
void LabelWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(Qt::black);
    //... Need an appropriate call to painter.translate() for this to work properly
    painter.rotate(90);
    painter.drawText(QPoint(0,0), _text);
}
```

Didn't need a QPixmap, it turns out.

Answer (score 25):

try using this:

```
#ifndef VERTICALLABEL_H
#define VERTICALLABEL_H

#include <QLabel>

class VerticalLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit VerticalLabel(QWidget *parent=0);
    explicit VerticalLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent=0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*);
    QSize sizeHint() const ;
    QSize minimumSizeHint() const;
};

#endif // VERTICALLABEL_H
```

///cpp

```
#include "verticallabel.h"

#include <QPainter>

VerticalLabel::VerticalLabel(QWidget *parent)
    : QLabel(parent)
{

}

VerticalLabel::VerticalLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent)
: QLabel(text, parent)
{
}

void VerticalLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(Qt::black);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::Dense1Pattern);

    painter.rotate(90);

    painter.drawText(0,0, text());
}

QSize VerticalLabel::minimumSizeHint() const
{
    QSize s = QLabel::minimumSizeHint();
    return QSize(s.height(), s.width());
}

QSize VerticalLabel::sizeHint() const
{
    QSize s = QLabel::sizeHint();
    return QSize(s.height(), s.width());
}
```

Comment: If you want to rotate by 270 instead, before the call to `painter.rotate(270)`, call `painter.translate( sizeHint().width(), sizeHint().height() )`.

Comment: For those Qt newbies (like me): you can use a normal label as a placeholder for this VerticalLabel in Qt creator, and just promote it to your custom type. See here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Comment: This version ignores alignment. For an alignment-aware version, replace `painter.drawText(0,0, text())` with `painter.drawText(0, 0, height(), width(), alignment(), text())`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a variant of Mostafa's implementation.

```
void VerticalLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

//    painter.translate(sizeHint().width(),0);
//    painter.rotate(90);
    painter.translate(0,sizeHint().height());
    painter.rotate(270);

    painter.drawText(QRect (QPoint(0,0),QLabel::sizeHint()),Qt::AlignCenter,text());
}
```

basically i have removed setPen and setBrush to preserve stylesheet and i have used an overload of drawText that uses the rect instead of point. This allows to have the '\n' inside the text or use WordWrap as a flag.

Comment: I put `alignment()` for the alignment and changed from `sizeHint().height()` to `height()`, to make the text align to the height that my layout expanded my label to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no handy function in `QLabel` to do what you want, no.  So:

1. Use `QGraphicsView`, which allows you to transform items however you want.
2. Use `QPainter`. Probably the easiest approach would be to draw the text rotated into a `QPixmap`, then set it on your `QLabel`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to draw text rotated into a QPixmap?  I don't see any kind of `QPixmap::drawText()` function.

Comment: You use a QPainter to draw to all QPaintDevices, of which QPixmap is one.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a new `QGraphicsScene`, add to it QLabel and then rotate it. Like this:

```
QLabel* label = QLabel("Y axis"); 
QGraphicsScene scene;
QGraphicsProxyWidget  * proxy = scene.addWidget(label);
proxy->rotate(-45);
QGraphicsView view(&scene);
view.show();
```

Take a look at the [similar example](http://web.archive.org/web/20120918211110/http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/showQtExample.php?index=164&key=RotateQLabelwithQGraphicsProxyWidget#.UFjjgxmnzDc).