# Rotate QLabel and keep its functionality/stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, rotation, qt4

For a while now I am searching for an adequate method to rotate a QLabel - and most important to keep its functionality and stylesheets.

I've found a pretty interesting approach here: [Vertical QLabel, or the equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183050/vertical-qlabel-or-the-equivalent)

First I was satisfied because it efficiently rotated the label. Unfortunately the Stylesheet I've added (using a bigger font and other color) was completely lost and the alignment is gone as well (`myLabel_->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);` has no effect).

I've read `QPainter::drawStaticText` would provide more functionality but for me it doesn't work at all (I'm using the same code as in the solution before mentioned, just with the difference:

```
QStaticText qs = "Test1";
painter.drawStaticText(0,0,qs);
```

)

Using deprecated HTML ("`<b>...</b>`") instead of Stylesheets is also no use... Same as returning to a regular QLabel and using modern transformation stylesheets (http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation).

I'm pretty much running out of ideas now how I am able to keep the former properties of the QLabel and still be able to rotate it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to do that.

[QStylePainter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstylepainter.html) may help with the style:

```
#include<QStylePainter>
// ......
void LabelWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QStylePainter painter(this);
    painter.rotate(90);
    painter.drawText(0, 0, text());
}
```

This will draw text with properties defined by stylesheet, but this does not solve the alignment problem.

---

If your `drawStaticText` code use `rotate(90)` and doesn't show any thing, it is beacuse the text is rotated around the top-left point and `rotate(90)` will move the text out of the widget(Try `rotate(45)`, you will find part of the text is out of the widget). A simple solution is using [QPainter::translate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#translate) to move to the center.

Here is my code that support alignment:

```
#include<QStylePainter>
// ......
void LabelWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QStylePainter painter(this);

    // rotate at center
    painter.translate(rect().center());
    painter.rotate(90);
    painter.translate(-rect().center());

    painter.drawText(rect(), alignment(), text());
}
```

To support more features like word-wrapping:

```
#include<QStylePainter>
#include<QTextOption>
// ......
void LabelWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QStylePainter painter(this);

    // rotate at center
    painter.translate(rect().center());
    painter.rotate(90);
    painter.translate(-rect().center());

    QTextOption textOption;
    textOption.setAlignment(alignment());
    if (wordWrap()) {
        textOption.setWrapMode(QTextOption::WordWrap);
    } else {
        textOption.setWrapMode(QTextOption::NoWrap);
    }
    painter.drawText(rect(), text(), textOption);
}
```

You will have to add more features if you want other properties of the `QLabel`, there is no simple solution.

PS: If you want use `QStaticText` , make it a member variable.

> The QStaticText class enables optimized drawing of text when the text
>   and its layout is updated rarely.
>
> QStaticText provides a way to cache layout data for a block of text so
>   that it can be drawn more efficiently than by using
>   QPainter::drawText() in which the layout information is recalculated
>   with every call.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! The part with the stylesheet worked perfectly for me. Unfortunately I still cannot set the alignment (and I don't understand why to use QStaticText - and where). As using your code my Label vanished completely. Yet I could solve this problem with another idea. I've just moved my Label into a QGridLayout. And instead of using `myLabel_->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);` I used `mainLayout_->addWidget(myLabel_, 1, 0, Qt::AlignBottom);` - mainLayout_ is a QGridLayout. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use QGraphicsScene
it can show a copy of anythings with customizations of size and orientation :

```
QLabel* myLabel_= QLabel("vertical label"); 
QGraphicsScene scene;
QGraphicsProxyWidget  * proxy = scene.addWidget(label);
proxy->rotate(90);
QGraphicsView view(&scene);
view.show();
```

then you can replace `view` by old myLabel_ object